# Authentication credentials were not provided drf

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

when i trying to access api i'm getting this error:

```
 "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

i have included this in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',


),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)

}
```

my app api urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'',views.UserViewSet, 'user_list')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

my views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = User.object.all()
       serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializers
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import User


class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email','password')
```

my main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include(urls)),
path ('', include(user_urls)),
path('api/',include(api_urls)),
```

when i running localhost:8000/api i'm getting the error

Comment: Can you show the `serializer class`

Comment: i have added that in edits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access the api from the browsers url if you are using **TokenAuthentication**.
as said by **@DarkOrb** TokenAuthentication expects a authorization **header** with **token** as it's value.
So You must pass **token** whenever you call the **api**.
You can test your api using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com).

[image]

In above image i have passed token in headers of postman to access my api.
When you call your api from frontend side,pass your token along with the request.
If you just want to use your api in only desktop's browser,in that case you can use **SessionAuthentication** only.For mobile devices **Tokenauthentication** must be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

use this in your `settings.py` file, what is happening is that `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` expects a authorization header with token as it's value, but you can't send that with your browser, to browse API from browser you must have `SessionAuthentication` enabled.

Comment: @afk were you logged in? Ideally using this code you should be able to use API in postman and browser both. Also the order is important having session authentication first will give you csrf issue from postman.

Comment: What were you doing wrong? It's important to know why it wasn't working and what made it work.